# Can't see incoming messages in Empathy and Skype

Tags: empathy, skype

I have stalled Skype for empathy but only outgoing messages work. When I try to chat to friends I can't see their messages.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2):

[image] This needs to be added

[Skype API Plugin](http://eion.robbmob.com/)

for Pidgin/libpurple/Adium
by Eion Robb
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Skype running already, in the background.

Unfortunately, Empathy is able to communicate with Skype only if it is already running.

Here is the website for the [Skype to Empathy plugin](http://eion.robbmob.com/).

Comment: did you read the question?